# _classpath and _project files are not recognizable in win

Tags: java, eclipse

I developed Java program on MAC. I wanted to continue develop it in win, so I moved my project folder to windows PC. Somehow classpath and project files has underscore ( _ ) mark in front of the names instead of dot (.) so eclipse in windows does not recognize my project.
I cant rename these files to start with dot, because windows throws an error.

is there any work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line

```
rename _project .project
rename _classpath .classpath
```

Comment: that worked. I am not familiar to command line commands, so thanks.
Is there a reason why mac and win names these files different, or it is just to make our life harder?

Comment: If I had to guess, moving your folder between mac and windows changed the names automatically. AFAIK it's always `.project` and `.classpath` no matter what platform you're on.